# Channel data not displaying in channel loop, but does display in query module tag

Tags: channel, query, no-results

I recently had a client referred to me who has an existing EE build, v2.73, and some of their entries just stopped displaying on their templates. According to them, no code has changed and no software (EE or add ons) have been updated.

I created a blank template to put a simple channel loop in to try some of the common problems; dynamic="no", making sure all statuses are accounted for, show_expired, show_future_entries. None of it worked. Some entries' channel data would display, and others wouldn't. All entries, even the one's not displaying, are visible in the backend and I can see them in the database.

So I decided to see if I could pull out the data with the exp:query tag, and sure enough I can. I can pull the data of an entry with the exp:query tag, but not the same entry's data with an exp:channel:entries tag.

I've never encountered this before and have no idea how to troubleshoot it. Thought I'd see if anyone had any ideas.

The code below is on an otherwise blank template. The `{article_text}` field is mapped to `field_id_3` in the `exp_channel_data` table.

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="3208" dynamic="no"}

      Channel Tag:<br/>
      {article_text}<br/><br/>

{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_3 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = '3208' "}

      Query Module<br/>
      {field_id_3}

{/exp:query}
```

Both tags in the above block output content when I changed the `entry_id` to an article that is working on the front end. I'm straight up baffled. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd wager there is an extension/module throwing hidden errors. Turn profiler on or temporarily disable extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm digging through the profiler output now to see what I can see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was unrelated to native EE. After some investigation the problem seems to be with an add-on.

Comment: Most likely your host has upgraded PHP to a newer version that is incompatible with a module.

Comment: I consulted the host, they're still running PHP v5.3.10, Ubuntu 12.04LTS. So no updates to the environment for quite some time. Client just decided to disable the add-on at this point. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If that entry does not have the status of "Open", Make sure you set the status parameter to include what ever that entry has.  i. e. `status="Open|Draft|Review"`
The channel entries tag defaults to Open entries only.
The Query Module is ignoring status unless you explicitly set it in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both entries have a status of open, so unfortunately that's not what's going on.